# Workarounds to avoid 101 SOQL limit exception

Tags: apex, soql, change-set, governorlimits

I am in critical situation due to below error

> "System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101"

Whenever we are moving any changeset to production we are getting the above error.
We followed salesforce best practices to write apex classes and triggers. We tried Test.start() and Test.stop to refresh the soql query count but no use of this because we are having too many queries that are hitting in various triggers.

Also we are not able to see the full debug log due to 2MB size limit.

Is there any other way to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: you can review a code that cause it and find an issue in that triggers. you can also add something like if (Limit.getQueries() > 90) { throw new customException('Here'); } to get place where limit is almost out.

Comment: You can make a support request to get the 2M limit raised and then use tools like this [SOQL Extractor and Analyzer for Salesforce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/soql-extractor-and-analyz/deihalhihjdilndoidoclmhmgllebkfj) (awkward to get installed though - see its "Support" information for a workaround) to help review the logs. Typically you will see repeated queries caused by cycles in the trigger and workflow logic - not easy to find the cause or fix.

Comment: You can also change the log levels to lessen the log size.

Comment: Try to make your trigger deactivatable per some custom setting...

Comment: @kurunve - 1. am not able to see the debug of the code i want due to maximum debug size reached. 2. could you please put example for limit.getQueries()

Comment: @Lex - I tried different logging levels like logginglevel.Error, warn, info... But it is now showing inside the 2MB

Comment: @SergeyUtko - could you please elaborate more

Comment: You could wrap the SOQL queries with a [`isRunningTest()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm) method to exclude it while running the apex text class for example.

Comment: @KeithC - Is SOQL Extractor and Analyzer for Salesforce is appexchange application?. It is directing me to another post.

Comment: @SergeyUtko - I've already tried !Test.isRunningTest() method in triggers but still the problem persist

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen The "SOQL Extractor and Analyzer for Salesforce" is a Chrome extension so needs Chrome to work.

Comment: @KeithC - I added that extension to my chrome. That is very helpful but I need to get the full debug then only that extension will show all the query count

Comment: Perhaps you are making queries in your code inside loops? If that's the case then you need to rewrite your code.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen See Lex's suggestion: look at your logs and see what information doesn't look useful and turn that off via the log levels.

Comment: my random guess would be that you have a query(-ies) inside a loop(s) somewhere and that's why it hits the limit. Sharing relevant parts of your code would be helpful

Comment: hey guys. Thanks for all your valuable comments. I contacted salesforce support. They are saying there is query inside a loop. But I couldn't able to find the piece of code that is having query inside a loop. There are lot of triggers wrote by many users.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Developer Console, choose Debug / Change Log Levels... Click Add/Change next to the top entry, set all categories to None, except Profiling, which you set to Finest. Next, run your tests, then check the logs. You'll get a list of queries executed, plus the class or trigger that called them, and the number of executions. You can use Profiling to quickly identify where the most usage is occurring.